# Codeigniter ecommerce wire framework available? (to handle login, cart etc)

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce, wireframe

I've spent a while searching around with google but come up with a relative blank.

Having just quit my day job (!!) I'm going to spend the next few months writing a very specific ecommerce website. Due to the nature of the site, using an existing package like Mage is out of the question, so I'm going to dust off my programming hat and get stuck in with Code Igniter.

I realise there's a cart and session class already, but I was just wondering if anyone had put together a simple ecommerce / member wireframe so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

From all my googling I've only really found totalshopuk, but that's a bit too feature rich (and, with respect, not that well written.)

I've also come across http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro which looks closer to the mark, and I'll be investigating it after I've finished this :)

Any further suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I faced the same problem half a year ago - making some specific ecommerce solutions and still maintaining some features like membership handling, CMS features and a lot of extras in the form of frontend visual effect and features. The CMS part and frontend request came a little late in the the developing process, but as a developer you probably already know how that works ;)

I started my editor and went on whacking in CI. I'm a big fan of CI, but got a bit tired of reinventing the wheel (as you put it yourself) for almost every feature asked for. I started looking around for alternatives which could help me develop fast and get easy profit, but EllisLab (the people behind CI) already had something great: [ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/) - which is a fairly large CMS with all the features you need to start a complex eCommerce site. Best part? It's based on CodeIgniter and it's the same structure, libraries (and so on) when developing addons and extensions for ExpressionEngine.

Although it could seem a bit pricy, it didn't take me more then 3-4 hours developing for the customer before having paid for the license.

The main reason I recommend EE is that it's based on a framework I've worked with for so long that it doesn't take long to develop something extra for my customers.

eCommerce module is free for download and is easy to modify for your needs. Membership management is already integrated into EE.

Comment: Hi Repox, Thanks for the answer, I'll be spending a lot more time tomorrow looking into EE and, having done a bit of googling. CartThrob. Looks like the combination of the two MIGHT be what I'm after, but at the same time they look like total overkill for the ecomm application I have in mind so I might email the developer of cartthrob and see how flexible it is. Thanks for taking the time to reply.